# how to make my site responsive for smart phones

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

care-24-7.com/Test/

I have been trying to get my new site template to adapt to mobile devices. So far it works when I resize the browser window. Problem is it doesn't work on mobile devices. It displays as a regular web page.

Comment: Have you researched on this issue before coming here? Because if you write "Making website responsive for smart phones" on google, you will get abundant resources that will help you. In one word for those abundant resources, Try "Media Queries". (No negatives from me though)

Comment: yes i did not understand what to ask! because it working on browsers than why not on smart phones!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

You **Don't** wan't `maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no`  as the user won't be able to ZOOM in

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [meta view-port](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) tag.

Add this to your page for quick resolution.

```
<meta name="viewport"
    content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no' />
```

Comment: let me use this than i will inform you. @vishwanath